# Test Class For Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I develop a trigger May i know how to write a test class for below trigger

```
 trigger insertMember2 on Account (after update){
    List<Quote> QuoteList = new List<Quote>(); 

   if(Trigger.isAfter) {

      if(Trigger.isInsert) {

   for(Account temp : Trigger.old) {

     Quote member2 = new Quote();
     member2.ShippingStreet = temp.BillingStreet;
     member2.ShippingCity = temp.BillingCity;
     member2.ShippingState = temp.BillingState;
     member2.ShippingPostalCode = temp.BillingPostalCode;
      member2.ShippingCountry = temp.BillingCountry;
     QuoteList.add(member2);
  }
 }
}

 if(QuoteList.size() > 0)
    insert QuoteList;
 }
```

Answer (score 10):

Everybody wins when you invest in the semantics of your code, your platform literacy (and that of the people you work with) and the **context of the problem you are trying to solve** when you post a question on StackExchange.

Before writing tests, I recommend tidying the trigger up for the sake of yourself, the future maintainer:

1. give the trigger a meaningful name and make sure you are looking at the correct *event*:

   ```
   trigger AccountInsertQuote on Account (AFTER INSERT)
   ```
2. combine (or remove entirely) the superfluous `if` statements

   <del>`if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert)`</del>
3. make sure the Trigger context is correct (your `Trigger.old` will *always* be null during insert)
4. ```
   for(Account account : Trigger.new)
   ```

Now we have a trigger worth testing!

```
//Quotes must be enabled (Setup > Customize > Quotes > Settings)
trigger AccountInsertQuote on Account (after insert) {
    List<Quote> quotes = new List<Quote>();
    for(Account account : Trigger.new) {
        Quote member2 = new Quote(
            Name = account.Name,
            ShippingStreet = account.BillingStreet,
            ShippingCity = account.BillingCity,
            ShippingState = account.BillingState,
            ShippingPostalCode = account.BillingPostalCode,
            ShippingCountry = account.BillingCountry
        );
        quotes.add(member2);
    }
    insert quotes;
}
```

At this point, we can think about your test scenarios, what we want to achieve:

1. validate the Shipping fields are set as intended,
2. verify any required fields are safe when the Quote is inserted,
3. generate (eg) 200 account records (to detect SOQL in loops or volume issues)

Now you can begin to write your first test (then additional ones to address all above scenarios):

```
@isTest public class AccountQuoteMember2Test{

    static testMethod void testQuoteCreatedByAccountInsert() {
        Integer expectedQuotesBefore = 0;
        Integer actualQuotesBefore = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Quote];

        //act
        insert new Account(Name = 'Test');

        Integer expectedQuotesAfter = 1;
        Integer actualQuotesAfter = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Quote];

        //assert
        System.assertEquals(expectedQuotesBefore, actualQuotesBefore);
        System.assertEquals(actualQuotesBefore, actualQuotesAfter);
    }

}
```

You will discover:

- `Quote` requires you to provide an `OpportunityId` as it lives off Opportunity not Account,
- `Quote` requires a `Name` which you would need to copy off Account

Et cetera. For further reading it'd be good to check out the [Product and Schedule Objects ERD](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_products.htm) to see the relationship between Opportunity and Quote, and [Test Methods and Bulk Operations](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods) which you can apply to your trigger tests.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few issues with the trigger itself as it looks like its an update trigger, but your logic in the trigger is treating it as though its an insert trigger.  So basically this code will never run as you have it as an update trigger but the logic is in a `If` statement that only gets run if it's an insert.  I will assume for this its an insert trigger.  Also, you aren't linking the quote to an opportunity that would relate it back to the account, so you would want to do that as well.

While I won't flat out write the test class for you, I will try to help you write it yourself.

In general, if you want to test your apex code, you just need to follow 3 steps

**1. Create your data**

For your trigger above it looks like you just need to create an Account

```
Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account', etc, etc, etc); //add your attributes
```

**2. Instantiate the class/Fire your trigger**

If this were a class or controller, you would instantiate the class.  As this is a trigger, you want to create conditions that cause that trigger to fire.  As your trigger is an insert trigger, you would simply need to update the account you just created.

```
insert a;
```

**3. Test your logic (Most IMPORTANT, and often overlooked step)**

Your trigger is creating quotes based on the insert of an account.  So now you want to make sure that actually happened.  Query for the newly created quote.

```
Quote q = [Select Id, Name, ShippingStreet, ShippingCity, ShippingState, ShippingPostalCode From Quote];
```

*If you had attached the quote to an opp, I would add a Where condition that check*

```
Where Opportunity__r.AccountId =: a.Id;
```

Now, you just need to make sure the logic you wanted to perform actually occured

```
System.assertEquals(q.ShippingStreet, a.BillingStreet);
System.assertEquals(q.ShippingCity, a.BillingCity);
//Etc, Etc.
```

That is a very basic run through of how to write test code.  You would now want to check other conditions, such as bulk inserts, or inserts of accounts with unexpected data, but this is a high level that should get you started quite well.  Good luck.